# PrettyPhoto.js using blogengine.net 2.0

Tags: blogengine.net

I'm using BlogEngine.Net 2.0 and installed prettyphoto extension

but I dont know how to use prettyphoto in my post pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
rel="prettyPhoto"
```

to the anchor element surrounding your picture. Here is simple example from [project site](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/):

```
<a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="This is the title" /></a>
```